# ASP.NET MVC - Integrating zetetic security with NHibernate Membership Provider

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate, asp.net-membership, bcrypt

zetetic has a pretty sweet encryption library that includes support for bcrypt2. It looks like it should be straightforward enough to incorporate into an ASP.NET Membership Provider (in fact, instructions for the default provider can be found [here](http://zetetic.net/blog/2012/3/29/strong-password-hashing-for-aspnet.html)). I am using an NHibernate Membership Provider (found [here](http://nhmemberprovider.codeplex.com)) which seems to hard code the SHA1 hash format in it's EncodePassword function. My question is, how should this be adapted to work with BCrypt2 (specifically Zetetic's wrapper). This is something I greatly fear getting wrong, and I'm reluctant to take a stab at it myself lest it should "work" but have some hidden flaw that I am not qualified to find.

```
 private string EncodePassword(string password)
        {
            string encodedPassword = password;

            switch (PasswordFormat)
            {
                case MembershipPasswordFormat.Clear:
                    break;
                case MembershipPasswordFormat.Encrypted:
                    encodedPassword =
                        Convert.ToBase64String(EncryptPassword(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(password)));
                    break;
                case MembershipPasswordFormat.Hashed:
                    HMACSHA1 hash = new HMACSHA1();
                    hash.Key = HexToByte(_machineKey.ValidationKey);
                    encodedPassword =
                        Convert.ToBase64String(hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(password)));
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new ProviderException("Unsupported password format.");
            }

            return encodedPassword;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you modifying the NHibernate-based membership provider, or stuck using it out of the box?  If the latter, it doesn't look like there's any extensibility.

The ASP.NET SqlMembershipProvider works by accepting the name of a hash algorithm, conjures an instance via [HashAlgorithm.Create(name)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wet69s13) and then behaves a little differently if the algorithm type turns out to be a KeyedHashAlgorithm or regular (non-keyed) HashAlgorithm.  The Zetetic.Security package is just providing a little bit of glue to make BCrypt and PBKDF2 compatible with that model.

The sample code from NHMembershipProvider can't take advantage of that because it's very directly relying on HMACSHA1.  I'd note that HMACSHA1 is not a secure algorithm for this purpose, nor is using a static salt for all users acceptable (it's scarcely better than no salt).  The app ValidationKey and HMACSHA1 are meant for message integrity only.

Here's a sample:

```
public class HashDemo
{
    private static readonly RNGCryptoServiceProvider s_rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();

    public string HashPassword(string pwd, string hashName)
    {
        var alg = HashAlgorithm.Create(hashName);

        if (alg == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid hash name", "hashName");

        byte[] tohash = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pwd);

        var ka = alg as KeyedHashAlgorithm;

        if (ka != null)
        {
            if (ka.Key == null || ka.Key.Length == 0)
            {
                byte[] key = new byte[20];

                s_rng.GetBytes(key);

                ka.Key = key;
            }
            else
            {
                s_rng.GetBytes(ka.Key);
            }
            // TODO: return base64(ka.Key || alg.ComputeHash(tohash))
        }
        else
        {
            var salt = new byte[20];

            s_rng.GetBytes(salt);

            using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(salt))
            {
                ms.Write(tohash, 0, tohash.Length);

                tohash = ms.ToArray();
            }
            // TODO: return base64(salt || alg.ComputeHash(tohash))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am modifying the NHibernate-based provider, so am at liberty to make modifications. It sounds (correct me if i'm wrong) like I need to pull out the EncodePassword implementation and insert a call to HashAlgorithm.Create?

Comment: One more thought - if you're rolling a MembershipProvider anyway, you might want to allocate separate columns for the hash alg name and parameters and hash output, in case you ever want to change from (let's say) BCrypt to SCrypt, or alter the work factor, the people with BCrypt hashes could still login.

Comment: Thanks @SKradel - Your answer was very insightful. I'm moving away from using zetetics solution as it is more straightforward to invoke bcrypt directly from the MembershipPasswordFormat.Hashed case in the switch statement in the EncodePassword function (if i were not using a custom provider i would definitely go with the zetetic solution...). I really like the idea of storing both the algorithm and the work factor with each record and I plan to go a step further and rehash passwords upon login when the user's work factor does not match the current work factor used by the site.

Comment: Supporting straight BCrypt would be a good choice -- one of the nice things about the string BCrypt produces is that it embeds its own version number and work factor, making it pretty painless to upgrade over time.  The main purpose of Zetetic.Security is to make better algorithms available to the SqlMembershipProvider (or other bits that work with named HashAlgorithms) without changing any of the code.  Otherwise, "just use bcrypt" is sound advice.